# Cannot deploy Cloud Function on Flutterflow

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, flutterflow

I am try to deploy my code to firebase cloud function through flutterflow but it keep failing. Previously I managed to do it successfully but I deleted the function on flutterflow then deleted it on the firebase console because it was not deleted in the firebase console.

Then I added a new function on flutterflow, same code for the function but this time it failed.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// To avoid deployment errors, do not call admin.initializeApp() in your code
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.updateInventoryOnPurchase = functions.firestore
  .document('purchaseLine/{purchaseLineId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const data = snapshot.data();
    const businessId = data.businessId;
    const itemId = data.itemId;
    const itemQty = data.itemQty;
    console.log(`businessId: ${businessId}, itemId: ${itemId}, itemQty: ${itemQty}`);
    // Reference to the inventory document
    const inventoryRef = db.collection('inventory')
      .where('businessId', '==', businessId)
      .where('itemName', '==', itemId);
    try {
      // Use a Firestore transaction to update the itemStock field in the matching inventory document
      await db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
        const inventoryQuerySnapshot = await transaction.get(inventoryRef);

        if (inventoryQuerySnapshot.empty) {
          throw new Error('Inventory item not found');
        }
        inventoryQuerySnapshot.forEach((inventoryDoc) => {
          const currentStock = inventoryDoc.data().itemStock || 0; // Default to 0 if field doesn't exist
          const newStock = currentStock + itemQty;

          // Update the itemStock field in the inventory document
          transaction.update(inventoryDoc.ref, { itemStock: newStock });
        });
      });
      console.log(`Inventory updated for item: ${itemId} with businessId: ${businessId}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating inventory:', error);
    }
  });
```

Deploying function to cloud function from flutterflow.